# On Windows Phone's IE Touchstart Event Ends Automatically After Few Seconds

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, windows-phone, touchstart

I have a very specific problem. I'm writing a web-page for mobile phones which has a button on it. I'm detecting `touchevent` on every browser including IE, but on IE it's quite specific. After a few seconds it automatically ends. Can you somehow help me? Here is my code (modified one, but still not working properly):

```
if (window.navigator.pointerEnabled) {
    tapButton.addEventListener("pointerup", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        addClass(this, 'clicked');
        buttonTouched = true;
    }, false);
    tapButton.addEventListener("pointerdown", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        removeClass(this, 'clicked');
        buttonTouched = false;
    }, false);
    alert("pointerEnabled");
}
else if (window.navigator.msPointerEnabled) {
    tapButton.addEventListener("MSPointerDown", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        addClass(this, 'clicked');
        buttonTouched = true;
    }, false);
    tapButton.addEventListener("MSPointerUp", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        removeClass(this, 'clicked');
        buttonTouched = false;
    }, false);
    alert("mspointerEnabled");
}
else {
    alert("ordinary touch");
    tapButton.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        addClass(this, 'clicked');
        buttonTouched = true;
    }, false);
    tapButton.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        removeClass(this, 'clicked');
        buttonTouched = false;
    }, false);
}
```

And the html tag has in it:

```
-ms-touch-action: none !important;
touch-action: none !important;
```

but that does not help either.

Comment: You didn't say which version of IE you're seeing this one, but I see that you're detecting the vendor prefixed events before the non-prefixed events.  Per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263112.aspx#document_object_model__dom__improvements, the prefixed versions are deprecated and should only be used when the non-prefixed versions are not available.  Perhaps reordering things will help.  The prefixed versions will, at some point, no longer work at all.

Comment: I was trying to fix the problem with vendor prefixes but it didn't help :( I only had the one without prefixes and it was acting the same :( any other suggestions?

Comment: Add working code snippet please, can't understand your problem.

Comment: Please see live project I made http://sheav.se/en and you will see everything. I cannot make snipped as it's very specific case

Comment: This problem appears only for IE 10 mobile. `pointerup` always fire for static gesture event - touch and hold. I tried to prevent it, but it fire always.

Comment: Yeap, I also tried to somehow prevent it but nothing worked :(

Comment: On a Win**8** phone, after showing the button for about 1 second, I have this message `Sorry, you cannot pou beer from your smartphone` how can I debug this?

Comment: That means your smartphone does not support window.ondevicemotion or has no gyroscope

Comment: I'm sorry but I think you have some background problem, cause my phone has a working gyroscope and supports `window.ondevicemotion`.
Connecting the phone from the page opened in Chrome gives me the same message but the beer mug is moving when tilting the phone (in IE no).

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that this is a hardware issue, i.e. some phones are just too quick to fire `pointerup`. In my own testing, I have found that if I use my entire thick thumb to firmly press the button, the erratic `pointerup` never fires. But if I use a thin fingertip or fingernail, the `pointerup` fires after ~0.5s to 1.5s, possibly because the phone was too quick to trigger a "finger release".

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are running into a multi-touch issue...

Remember, touch events are not the same as mouse events. You can touch with more than one finger. What happens if you touch with one finger than add a second finger? You get two consecutive `touchstart` events. The same is probably true for `touchend`. I suspect user `light` is right that it's probably triggering a finger release incorrectly...

Please have a look at what is happening to the `touches`, `changedTouches` and `targetTouches` properties of the [TouchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent) you get in your listener. I strongly suspect you'll see that there still is a 'finger' left touching... So it went from 2 touches to 1...

Making sure that the (no longer) touching finger is actually the one that's on the button etc is all a lot less simple than the good old `mouseup` and `mousedown` events were.

EDIT: I realize your problem is with IE and it's pointer events... However they work mostly the same in that they too support multi-touch (and could thus suffer the same issues). I'm not seeing a property akin to `touches`, but I do see a `pointerId`, which can give you the same info (at the cost of some bookkeeping on your end).

[This MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn433244(v=VS.85).aspx) has some good info. Especially this code snippet is enlightening I think:

```
function pointerdownHandler(evt) {
      evt.target.setPointerCapture(evt.pointerId);
}
```

This seems to confirm that, when a finger hits the surface, the contact point gets an ID, which is used to inform you which finger left the surface when you receive the `pointerup` event.

I'd add some logging that just prints the `pointerId` on `pointerdown` and `pointerup` and I'll bet you will quickly find your solution.